# Server only receives metadata when uploading a file from React Native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express, nestjs

I have a React Native client and NestJS server. I'm trying to record an audio and send the file to the server.
The API endpoint seems to work fine when I tried testing it with Postman and React. However, when I uploaded a file with React Native, the server only receives metadata but the content is an `empty Buffer` with `size 0`. Inside the `stopRecording`  handler, I have already checked that, before sending the request, the formData does actually contain the content of the audio file.

React Native code inside a component

```
const AudioInput3 = () => {
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState<Recording | null>(null);
  const [recordingStatus, setRecordingStatus] = useState("idle");
  const [audioPermission, setAudioPermission] = useState(false);

const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
      if (audioPermission) {
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
          allowsRecordingIOS: true,
          playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        });
      }

      const newRecording = new Audio.Recording();
      await newRecording.prepareToRecordAsync(
        Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH
      );
      await newRecording.startAsync();

      setRecording(newRecording);
      setRecordingStatus("recording");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to start recording", err);
    }
  };


async function stopRecording() {
    try {
      if (!recording) return;
      if (recordingStatus === "recording") {
        await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
        const recordingUri = recording.getURI() as string;

        const filename = `recording_${Date.now()}.caf`;

        const filePath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "recordings/";

        setRecording(null);
        setRecordingStatus("stopped");

        const fileData = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(recordingUri, {
          encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
        });

        const blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: "audio/x-caf" });
        const file = new File([blob], filename, {
          type: "audio/x-caf",
        });

        const fileSize = file.size;
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        const response = await fetch(urlResolver.uploadToStorage(), {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            "Content-Length": String(fileSize),
          },
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

What I have tried.

1. Some solutions mentioned to remove the request header, which doesn't work for me.
2. Replace fetch with `axios` also doesn't work
3. Turned off `react-native-debugger` also does not work.

My NestJS API endpoint is as follows. (This works normally when a file is uploaded from React or Postman)

```
@Post("upload")
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("file"))
  uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(file); 
  }
```

which returns the following result. (Empty Buffer and file size === 0)

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'recording_1683615927273.caf',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'audio/x-caf',
  buffer: <Buffer >,
  size: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work despite the fact that the type is wrong. (Had to cask the file to `any`)

```
.
.
.
        const file = {
          uri: recordingUri,
          name: "audio.m4a",
          filename: "audio.m4a",
          type: fileType,
        };


        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file as any);

        const response = await fetch(endpointUrl, {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        });
        );
```